# Partial View not showing up MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to create a partial view for a calendar and it's not showing up I don't know why. I try to display the partial view with:

```
<div>
@{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Calendar");
}
```

I don't know what the problem is...If I made a button in my navigation bar with:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Booking" asp-action="Calendar">Calendar</a>
```

and then in the BookingController simply do this:

```
 public class BookingController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Calendar()
    {
        return View("_Calendar");
    }
}
```

There it shows up..but not in the Booking Index like it should. Here are some images:
[image]

The red rectangle is where I want the _Calendar to be. This Image if what shows if I go to _Calendar using the nav bar:
[image]

The _Calendar partial view is in my shared folder. Let me know if you need any more information.

So I added a

## TEST

inside the _Calendar and that shows up but the calender does not:
[image]

Comment: Would it not be `return PartialView("_calendar")`?

Comment: Where in the BookingController ? how ? I only use the return View("_Calendar"); for the navigation bar button and there it works. But I want the _Calendar to show up in the Booking Index that is why it should just show up when i do IActionResult Index return View(). It works with smaller and simpler partial views like <h1>Test</h1>

Answer (score 1):

If you have js code in _Calendar,the page which refernces _Calendar  will not load the js code.And you need to put the js code of _Calendar into the page which refernces _Calendar.
Here is a demo worked.
Main.cshtml(reference a partial view):

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Main";
}

<h1>Main</h1>
<div style="height:400px;width:400px;border:1px solid red;">
    <partial name="_partial1" />
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#div1").text("Hello World!");
    </script>
}
```

_partial1.cshtml(in Shared folder):

```
<div id="div1">
</div>
```

result:

[image]